# INSERT even though column does not exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have an old .SQL dump and since it was created, I have changed the table schema.

I could be running:

```
INSERT INTO `ec_product_campaign_relations` (`campaign_id`, `product_id`, `product_qty`) VALUES (30,28,1),(30,27,0),(30,31,0),(30,30,0);
```

But if column product_qty does no longer exist, the line will not get inserted.

How can I force the line to get inserted anyways and ignore that the column does not exist?

EDIT: It should mention I'm working in PHP and it is script used to sync table shema... So no "manual" control over this.

Comment: Remove it from the column list and the values list? You'll have to come up with a way to split the string into chunks and delete the ones you don't want.  Maybe import it into Excel or something?

Comment: Add the column to the table, run the SQL and remove the column?

Answer (score 1):

Since editing all your SQL dump won't be trivial, I suggest you to add the column to your table, make the import, then delete the column.

Comment: I could do that, but I would somehow have to identify which columns was created while running the queries? I forgot to mention I'm working in PHP on this - just added it to my question... Makes it a lille more complicated.

Comment: Effectively, automaticaly identify these columns will be a little bit more difficult :P You'll have to query your database to know which columns exists, parse your dump to identify the columns presents in it, then compare these 2 lists, and finally add the missing columns... You have to do this a lot of time? If not, I don't think it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a new database for this import and restore the dump as-is. Then, once you've got a handle on what changes have been made by comparing the schema in one to the new one, create a series of `ALTER TABLE` statements that bring it in sync.

I tend to record these in a text file in case I need to replay them later, and also keep them as a list of what's changed. You may have to do this more than once, so notes help.

Then, once you've cleaned them up to be column-compatible, dump this database table-by-table, and restore into the other as required.